# Cannot properly modify list of dictionaries

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

I am trying to supply `initial` (`es_initial`) data to my `formset`, where `initial` is a list of dictionaries. My view.py have following code:

```
        # get all answers by  current student
        es_answers_by_student = models.Answer.objects.filter(
            student__user=request.user
        ).filter(
            question__quiz=step
        ).filter(
            eq_answer_text__icontains=''
        )
        # supply question prompt to the initial data
        for es_question in eqs:
            es_dict_for_initial.update({'question': es_question.prompt},)
            es_initial.append(es_dict_for_initial.copy())
        # supply saved answers
        for answer in es_answers_by_student:
            for _dict in es_initial:
                _dict["eq_answer"] = answer.eq_answer_text

        print(es_initial)
```

Cannot understand, why my last `for` loop always returns same value which is the last value in `es_answers_by_student` queryset

**Edit:**

After performing the first `for` loop, `es_initial` looks like:

```
 [{'question': 'question text 1'}, {'question': 'question text 2'}]
```

Here is what I want to accomplish after the second `for` loop:

```
[{'question': 'question text 1', 'eq_answer': 'answer text 1'},
 {'question': 'question text 2', 'eq_answer': 'answer text 2'}]
```

Comment: it's expected: you loop on `answer` and your inner loop assigns the same dictionary data, not depending on `answer`. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Can you supply a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Your last `for` loop writes the last value in the `es_answers_by_student` list (?) to each dict in the `es_initial` list, but what do you expect/want it to do instead?

Comment: You'd better showed how it looks like after all loops now

Comment: it looks like following [{'eq_answer': 'text of an answer', 'question': 'Question text 1?'}, {'eq_answer': 'text of an answer', 'question': 'Question text 2?'}, {'eq_answer': 'text of an answer', 'question': 'Question text 3?'}, {'eq_answer': 'text of an answer', 'question': 'Question text 4?'}].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to loop over the `_dict`s, and change the answer within the loop, something like this:

```
for _i, dict in enumerate(es_initial):
    _dict["eq_answer"] = es_answers_by_student[i].eq_answer_text
```

This implicitly assumes that the ordering of the `es_initial` and `es_answers_by_student` is the same, if not you have to find some way to index into the `es_answers_by_student` list to find the right item.

Comment: Thanks Nils Gudat, it worked for me. I am still in the process of learning python and django